# syncing an outlook account with gmail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

I would like (on the client side, say through Outlook) to periodically take new messages from my outlook account and upload them to my gmail account (but not the other way around).

What is the way to do it? I noticed there is something called GWMMO, but it is only for Windows, and I use a mac. I couldn't find any further information.

This needs to be done, again, on the local client side, so I can't set on outlook.com, for example, to forward emails to my gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I noticed that you want to sync the emails of an Outlook account to an Gmail account, and you can't create a rule to forward emails to your Gmail account, right?

If so, as I know, both the rule created in Outlook for mac client or on outlook.com can be available and can be used to forward the emails of the Outlook account to Gmail account successfully.

**To create a forwarding rule in Outlook for mac**: Tools>Rules…>Sever rules>choose your Outlook account>on the right, click "+", create a rule as shown in below figure

[image]
[image]
[image]

**To create a forwarding rule on outlook for web**: Settings>Mail>Rules, create a rule as shown in below figure
[image]

Hope the above help!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.